# How to fix a small gap in wedi corner?

Tags: bathroom, shower, bathtub, renovation

First time posting here. I’m working on my first bathroom remodel. Unfortunately, I did not notice a small gap forming on the right side. I thought it was going to just be a small constant gap. I’m sure it’s something easily preventable and an obviously stupid mistake on my part. My first thought is to use the wedi joint sealant and the second is to use some furring strips to close the gap but I’m unsure of the best method to proceed. [image: close up image of gap] [image: wide angle image of install]

Comment: This gap is going to be covered when you put in the other wedi board on the right, isn't it?

Comment: I read it needs a 1/4” overlap and my wedi board is 1/2” thick. 3/4 of the way up it has the 1/2” gap so by the top it certainly would’ve been enough of a gap to get a quarter through…I ended up cutting out a section and replacing it with a bigger piece to shrink the gap